# Logarithmic limit

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x \to0}\frac{ln(\cos(2x))}{x^2}.$$

So, I tried solving it but I didn't get an answer and I have no idea how to solve this without differentiation, Taylor series or more complex than that. Is there a easy way?

Comment: l'Hopital's Rule works easily for this. Advanced methods and deeper results often make problems easier.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\log(\cos 2x)}{x^2}=\frac{\log(1-2\sin^2x)}{\sin^2x}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}.$$

The second fraction tends to one, and we can rewrite the first as

$$2\frac{\log(1-t)}{t}.$$

Now you can conclude knowing this limit, or equivalently (by a suitable change of variable) that of

$$\frac{e^z-1}z.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(\cos2x)}{x^2}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{2}\frac{\ln(\cos^22x)}{x^2}=
\lim_{x\to0}2\frac{\ln(1-\sin^22x)}{(2x)^2}=
\lim_{x\to0}2\frac{\sin^22x}{(2x)^2}\frac{\ln(1-\sin^22x)}{\sin^2(2x)}
$$
and recall that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}=-1
$$
However, Taylor expansion is much easier:
$$
\ln(\cos2x)=\ln\left(1-\frac{(2x)^2}{2}+o(x^2)\right)=-2x^2+o(x^2)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Classic case of using the L'Hospital's rule, since both the numerator and denominator converge to 0 when $x \rightarrow 0$.

$lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{ln(cos(2x))}{x^2}$

$= lim_{x \rightarrow 0} -\frac{tan(2x)}{x}$

$= lim_{x \rightarrow 0} -2 sec^2(x) = -2$.

I skipped some details, but it is basically an application of L'Hospital's rule at each step.